# How to set checked Checkbox based on database record?

Tags: jsp, checkbox

I would like to raise a question about JSP checkbox

I want to loop the subscription list from the database.

At the same time, I loop the specific user's subscription request.

For example, in the subscription list, there are several items, says

```
System Analyst
System Developer
System Manager
System Tester
```

In the subscription list, the user subscribed 2 of them, says

```
System Manager
System Tester
```

In the looping, I will loop a table with a checkbox column to show all the subscription value.

I encounter a problem here.

I want to make the checkbox "checked" while the user has subscribed the item.

For example, the result of table should have "checked" 2 of the checkbox.

However, I don't know the algorithm to implement my logic.

Can anyone kindly provide some hints for me to realize this?

Thanks.

siris

Coding-

```
<tr>
    <td>Subscription:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="subscription"> 

//read the subscription List
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from subsrciption");

//read the user has subscipted what item(s)
ResultSet rs2=statement.executeQuery("select * from request where userid='testing' ");
//in this SQL, for userid-testing, we find 2 records that he subscribed 2 items

//loop the subscription list from database
while ( rs.next() ) {
  String subscription = rs.getString("subscription");
  //after read the subscription table, how to loop the request table
  //while ( rs2.next() ) {

%>
  <option value="<%=subscription%>"><%=subscription%></option>
<%
  //} 
} //end loop subscription list

%>
    </select>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked about checkbox in the question and writing for Select in code.

Please edit your post.
Use

```
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="<%=subscription%>"><%=subscription%>
```

Secondly,

Get subscription value from `rs2` and compare it with `rs`