# Spring MVC and JSP - Mapping Boolean into model

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an class that contains an Boolean attribute

```
class A {
    Boolean marked;

    [here getter and setter]
}
```

On my jsp page I connect the checkbox to the model attribute:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="updateA" modelAttribute="myAInstance">
    <form:checkbox path="marked"/>Valid<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>                             
</form:form>    

...

<span>From the DB: ${myAInstanceFromDB} </span>  // this displayes true
```

When submitting the `Controller` gets the correct value (`myAInstance`) and I save it in the `DB`. But if I reload the page (`myAInstanceFromDB`) the `checkbox` I have previously selected and saved is not checked. I guess it's beause the path of the checkbox points to `modellattribute` to be post to the `server` and not to the `database` object I past to the page. How do I mark the checkbox when loading the page?

Comment: what is the value you are saving in DB?

Comment: I use MySQL and hibernate. The property in the java class is Boolean and the DB-column is of type bit(1). Using MySQL Workbench I see a 1 (for true) when I execute a select.

Comment: Here are some of the answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845741/setting-jsp-checkbox-with-a-value-from-database
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052003/how-to-set-checked-checkbox-based-on-database-record

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myVal" id="myVal" value="checkVal" <%= ("true".equals(myAInstanceFromDB) ? "checked" : "") %>>
```

Another way is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myVal" id="myVal" value="checkVal" ${myAInstanceFromDB == 'Head' ? 'checked' : ''}>
```

Comment: Do I have to use that standard input type checkbox? I am using spring so I have <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> <form:checkbox path="marked">. It does not have a checked attribute. But it has a path, which makes it very comfortable to pass attributes inside a model.